# Hot to write an In-Memory GDAL Dataset to disk with python

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-python-bindings

I'm trying to write an IN-Memory Dataset to a GeoTiff in Disk with gdal for python

```
gd_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("MEM")
gd_raster = gd_driver.Create('pippo', src_height, src_width, src_NBands, gdal.GDT_Int16)
gd_raster.SetGeoTransform(gd_transform)
gd_raster.SetProjection(src_crs.wkt)

for i in range (0, src_NBands):
  gd_raster.GetRasterBand(i+1).WriteArray(src_data[i])

# TO tiff
drv_out = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
dset_in = gdal.Open('/vsimem/pippo', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

drv_out.CreateCopy(file_name_out, dset_in)
```

but i can not open and read source dataset

Comment: What specific issue are you encountering?

Comment: a try open the MEM as '/vsimem/pippo' but i return None. I didn't know hot to use createCopy with MEM as source.

Comment: I don't see where you are doing that in your code. Please post all relevant code and the output in your question.

Comment: I just want test how to use In-Memory Gdal Dataset. I Understand how to create it from a source but I don't know how to wirte it to disk.  Once the In-Memory dataset has been processed, how to write it to disk

Comment: What format is the data you are trying to write to disk?

Comment: I'd like to write it to GeoTiff

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

I have to put the source dataset (In Memoery dataset) in the second argument of createcopy without open it before

```
...
# TO tiff
dset_tiff_out = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
# dset_tiff_in = gdal.Open('/vsimem/pippo', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

dset_tiff_out.CreateCopy(file_name_out, gd_raster, 1)
...
```

many thanks